# My copied projects appears in brackets next to the new one

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Well I copied `elite-core` and rename it to `travel`. But in this is what happens [image]

Why  is that and will it make some conflicts with my new project ?
I mean I am in the `travel` project now and there is `elite-core` in the end.

Comment: Did you change the project name as well? Custom project name is stored in `.idea/name` file.

Comment: Well I deleted the folder and the IDE generated it again. It's fine now. Thank you :)